Sub panel lugs too big
I currently have a 4-space subpanel on the side of my house and need 6 spaces.
So I went and bought the next size Siemens 8-space panel thinking everything would match.
Turns out I the A,B,N lugs are rated for #4 - 2/0, unlike my smaller panel that supports #14.
My feeder wire is only #10 and was compatible with the smaller 4-space panel.
How can I attach the #10 feeder?
Also, code apparently says more than 6 disconnects requires a main breaker?
I’ll end up having 2x 2-pole, 1x tandem, and 1x regular. Is that 5? I don’t necessarily need a main right?
This panel supports a back feed main breaker too, should I use that to get around the wire size requirement? Will any Siemens breaker work? I know about the hold down kit, but the compatibility stuff is confusing me.

First of all, consider a much larger panel. You don't need a 40 space panel here, but 12 spaces instead of 8 might be well worth it to avoid having to do this again in a few years. Your current plan (if I understand it correctly) uses 6 spaces already and if you end up with a backfed main breaker then all 8 spaces will be filled.
The rule you are referencing regarding the need for a main breaker is called "Rule of Six" - at most 6 actions to turn off everything. Each double-breaker is one throw, so even if your tandems are separate you are OK. I am actually not sure if there is any need for Rule of Six/Main Breaker here because while the panel is outside, it is on the same building as the main panel (which does have the Rule of Six or main breaker requirement).
That being said, a backfed main breaker is indeed a solution to the wire size problem. For example, a 60A QP breaker will accept wire as small as 6 AWG, and you can use an Ideal 454 Blue wire nut to connect 6 AWG to 10 AWG.
If you don't limit yourself to Siemens then you have more options. A quick search finds a similar Eaton BR816L125RP that, at least in the specs I can find, can handle as small as 14 AWG wires.
